# Deploy firebase storage triggerd function on different environments

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm having trouble to deploy my firebase function on my production environment since the buckets between dev and prod have different names. They are not the default buckets.

```js
exports.myFunction= functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .storage
    .bucket("myDevBucket")
    .object()
    .onFinalize(
        async (object) => {
           [My code]
        });
```

I struggle finding a way to use a variable instead of "myDevBucket" to be able to deploy using my CD on the production.

If you have any tips on that, I'll be glad to hear about them...
Thanks

Tried to use an .env variable which is not used during function deployment, so the default bucket was automatically selected.

Tried to use the `defineString` params firebase function, but the storage.bucket() does not handle these params (only the `runWith()` if I have understood correctly).

Comment: Same problem here, occurring also with Gen2 Cloud functions.

Here some ref issues about it:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1413
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1369